# Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

When I run the following code in Visual Studio 2013, it shows:

`Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or one of its base types`

```
Private Sub Application_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, _
    ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.DocumentBeforeSave
    Doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.InsertParagraphBefore()
    Doc.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text = "This text was added by using code." 
End Sub
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem?
The code above is from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442946.aspx

Answer (score 0):

That code assumes that the current class has a field named `Application` of type `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application` (which includes the `DocumentBeforeSave` event)

1. Create a new Word 2013 Add-In project
2. Open the `ThisAddin.vb` file
3. Notice that this class also has a partial class defined in `ThisAddin.Designer.vb`, in which the `Application` field is declared:

```
Friend WithEvents Application As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
```